# FutureBuilder doesn't work without touching the screen

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I have the following situation: there's a button on the screen, which adds data to db. And there's the future builder which has future `getDataFromDB`. When I add data by button, the future builder doesn't get data from DB. And when I do several swipes on the screen it works correctly. What's the matter? Here's the code:

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: DatabaseManager().findAllCaloriesForSelectedDate(currentDate),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      _caloriesCurrent = snapshot.data;
                      return AnimatedCircularChart(
                        size: Size(constraints.maxWidth * 0.8, constraints.maxWidth * 0.8),
                        initialChartData: <CircularStackEntry>[
                          CircularStackEntry(
                            <CircularSegmentEntry>[
                              CircularSegmentEntry(
                                currentProgress,
                                Color(AppColors.brandViolet),
                              ),
                              CircularSegmentEntry(
                                100 - currentProgress,
                                Color(AppColors.layoutBackgroundColor),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                        chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
                        edgeStyle: SegmentEdgeStyle.round,
                        percentageValues: true,
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  },
                )
```

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide your whole build method or widget for full context.

Answer (score 0):

There're two problems with your code:

1. You're obtaining Future object within build function which isn't right way to do it. Every time your widget rebuilds, you get new Future object (so, maybe, it rebuilds when you touch/scroll). You should store Future object in State of your Widget.

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder.

2. You're using FutureBuilder, but you expect FutureBuilder to rebuild after you change some data. FutureBuilder doesn't work like that and rebuilds only once - when Future value is resolved (if you store Future object within State. In your case, it always gets new Future on rebuild). You probably want to use StreamBuilder. It will allow you to add new data to the stream of data. StreamBuilder will trigger on stream changes and automatically rebuild.

You should read about BloC Architecture, in case you haven't.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I didn't understand a bit your first point. Do you mean that I should move my `NutritionDataManager().getDishes(currentDate)` to separate method which return `Future` or I am wrong?

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii You call findAllCaloriesForSelectedDate method that returns you Future object. You shouldn't call this method inside _build_. Instead, call it in initState or somewhere else and store the result Future object in State.

Comment: but if I update data and when the screen rebuilds I need to show updated data. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii You just use _setState_ to set a new Future value - FutureBuilder will rebuild with new Future from State. But I recommend using _StreamBuilder_, so you can just add new data to the stream and the widget will rebuild.

Comment: As I understand streamBuilder works as usual bus, isn't it? So, we put the value in one widget and take it in another. But how can I pass callback to another widget that I put this value?